# Was spurious correlation of ratios inadvertently explained by Howe?

Tags: correlation

[Roger Howe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Roger_Evans_Howe) pointed out that vector sums tend toward convexity. Could this explain the [spurious correlation of ratios](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spurious_correlation_of_ratios)? The idea that I have is that division of one variable by another essentially turns the answer into a vector-like entity, and the resulting relatively-high positive correlation is simply a result of the geometry that is tending towards convexity. Is there anything to this?

Comment: What’s with the up-vote? Why isn’t Noah Schweber here, pointing out that there are only 5 google hits on ‘tending towards convexity’, and that I’m conflating very different phenomena?